# Howto ignore invalid values in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest

In 3.x versions android we have android:LargeHeap property.

But we have not this property in 2.x versions.

Then my question - is it possible to use this property in 3.x platforms and ignore it in 2.x platforms in same application? If the application installed in 3.x platform then we use the android:LargeHeap, and if the application installed in 2.x we ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes You need to specify min and target version of SDK and build your project with the at least the target version or above. This one you can set in your Eclipse->Android properties. This way when you run your APK on older version (down to minSdkVersion) the unsupported setting is ignored

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Comment: oh god, thank you. I just spent hours trying to fix a problem because I thought you had to build against the lowest version you want to support.